# Replace HTML tag based on attribute value

Tags: html, vue.js, webstorm, structural-search

I need to replace vanilla `<a>` tag by different tag (`<router-link>`) in whole project. The main problem is to do it with some conditions based on `href` value (e.g. it should ignore href with `"#"`).

I wrote regex, but it was really massive and sometimes cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found that webstorm(and other) has "Structural Replace" feature which help with it.
I create follow structural replace:
[image]
[image]
Main poins:

- `$before$` and `$after$` have count filter = [0, infinity]
- `$before$` ignore 'href'
- `$href$` has script which filter some values